# entity framework generates ugly foreign keys names

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, foreign-keys

When I generated the model of the database using ADO.NET Entity Data Model, the generated model had ugly foreign keys names. I tried to change the names in SQL Server Management Studio and then I generated the model again but it did not adopt the new names of the foreign keys.

So please could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not Entity Framework or ADO.NET that's auto-naming your foreign keys - it's SQL Server (most likely). If you don't like those names - then **you** must supply your own names!

Comment: I did but when it generates the names again it gives a new auto generated names not the names that I supplied in the sql server

Comment: Are you talking about reverse engineering an existing database into POCOs or forward engineering code first entities into a database?

Comment: You need to **define the names** in the model, so that they will be used when generating the database! Fixing them in the database *after* generating it of course won't help ... can you show us the configuration you have in code for one of those tables in question?

Comment: Are you speaking about the foreign key fields or the foreign key constraints?

Comment: @SteveGreene reverse engineering.

Comment: @marc_s what are the configurations that you are talking about and can you guide me or explain about what do you mena by defining the names of the constraints in the model.

if there is a link please comment it so I can read about the topic.

Comment: Are you using **code-first** EF with **migrations** ?

Comment: @marc_s No, I build the database first then I generate the model using it.

Comment: So then: when you build your database, aren't you **defining** the foreign key constraint's **names**??

Comment: @marc_s I did and finally I found out  the problem, the problem is that when you generate the model from the database there are tow things the first thing is the Association Set Name Property and the other thing is the End1 Navigation Property and you have to change the name of the last one by clicking on the relation in the model and then choose the properties and then change the End1 Navigation Property value to the name that you want, then POPUP will be shown about if you wanna change this property name in all files that have been effected.

Answer (score 0):

With automatic migration the name is assigned by EF.
With manual migration you can specify the name in AddForeignKey method. Here the specifications
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.addforeignkey(v=vs.113).aspx

**EDIT**
During automatic migration the EF build the name with this logic

```
FK_<sourceTable>_<targetTable>_<sourceFieldsList>
```

See EF framework source code ForeignKeyOperation.cs property DefaultName